# Chef Client Top and Bottom Level Attributes

Tags: chef-infra

I'm building a cookbook that has requirements on node attributes. If the node attributes don't exist I want to exit the client run and return an appropriate error. I'm trying to exit when the top-level attribute doesn't exist, i.e.:

```
# Check for valid keepalived configuration on node
if node.default['keepalived'] = ""
  Chef::Application.fatal!("No keepalived configuration was set on the node. Please add some.")
end
```

If node['keepalived'] is an array (as it should be) this fails. If it's empty (doesn't exist) then this passes.

**What statement should I use to exit if node['keepalived'] has not been set but continue if there are sub-values?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues, one you flubbed `=` vs `==`. Second the thing you want to check for is:

```
if !node['keepalived'] || node['keepalived'].empty?
```

Comment: Damn those = flubs :)